# Autofilter with 3 criterias

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried to use vba to autofilter 3 criteria but it isn't reading the both values given. Below is the code im using it just reads "MY18" and not "MY 18"

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=7
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$138").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="FY17"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$138").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("=*MY 18*", "=*MY18*") _
        , Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>*discussion*"



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In the below line

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$138").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("=*MY 18*", "=*MY18*") _
    , Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>*discussion*"
```

Replace, `Operator:=xlAnd` with `Operator:=xlFilterValues`

***EDIT :***

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$138").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("=*MY 18*", "=*MY18*", "<>*discussion*")
```

Comment: Great! that worked but now my not containing value discussion is not included. is there a way to get all 3 criteria?

Comment: @J.Khoo for separate fields or just for one?

Comment: @AntiDrondert it needs to have contains "MY18" and "MY 18" and not contain "discussion"

Comment: @J.Khoo just asking, string `*MY 18*` might contain discussion?.. If not you don't even need third condition.

Comment: @AntiDrondert afew of the string *MY18* and *MY 18* contains the string *discussion* which i would like to filter out

Comment: @J.Khoo does adding  `<>*discussion*` to an array work?

Comment: @J.Khoo - As @AntiDrodent said, use `ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$138").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("=*MY 18*", "=*MY18*", "<>*discussion*") `

Comment: @Mrig i have tried doing that but it gives me a runtime error or should i remove the operator:=xlFilterValues?

Comment: @J.Khoo - Remove `operator:=xlFilterValues`, just copy the above line in comments or see edit in answer.

Comment: @Mrig it seems to only read the last value in the Array, in this case it's only reading the "does not contain: discussion". The other 2 values in the array are disregarded

Comment: @J.Khoo - Give me sometime, I'll chcek.

Comment: @Mrig great! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me using the code below:

ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AJ50").AutoFilter Field:=7, *Criteria1:=Array("ABC", "DEF", "GHI"), Operator:=xlFilterValues*

I know it is too late but it may be useful for someone else.

Comment: Hi Graceial, please familiarise yourself with [answering questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before you write your next one! Happy coding!